# how to read all images alt in html page using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-testing

I am trying to test my website using selenium. And I want to check all images have filled alt attribute or not. So how to check this.

```
<img src="/media/images/biren.png" alt="N. Biren" class ="img-fluid" >
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should at least show us how far did you get, not ask us to do for you.

Comment: @Micky I'd suggest writing something first and asking in here how to solve the problem you have. I'm not sure you will get someone to just do the work / coding for you from the above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed with selenium, but this can be done easily using `requests` with `bs4` (simple web-scraping).

Please find an example code below:

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'HTML URL HERE!'
# get the url html txt
page = requests.get(url).text
# parse the html txt
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# get all img tags
for image in soup.find_all('img'):
    try:
        # print alt text if exists
        print(image['alt'])
    except:
        # print the complete img tag if not
        print(image)
```

Comment: This wont work if html is generated by js

Comment: The question asked for Selenium but you provide requests and beautifulsoup solution haha.

Comment: @ShaneMuirhead I apologize if I mentioned my answer works for selenium, I suggested this above solution just as an alternate way.